# HIve UDF Executes sysout statements twice

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hadoop2

I am creating an UDF and calling two methods inside it but when i create the  function and run the sql query it is printing sysout statements twice from these methods,though it processes exact no of rows that are present.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

HiveVerion:1.2.1

Comment: Perhaps illustrate your question with example data, example code and expected output.

Comment: Probably there are two mappers or reducers and your function running in parallel